# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered on a service

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to register a receiver for a foreground service on its onStartComand and unregister it onDestroy but

it shows java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered error

I have tried to register and unregister it through the application context but the same error

Here is a simplified version of my code :

```
   package bd.maruf.ruwifimanager
    
    import android.app.Service
    import android.content.Intent
    import android.content.IntentFilter
    import android.os.IBinder
    
    class Test: Service() {
        override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }
    
        override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    
            registerReceiver(
                WifiStateChangeReceiver(),
                IntentFilter("android.net.wifi.supplicant.STATE_CHANGE")
            )
    
            return START_NOT_STICKY
        }
    
        override fun onDestroy() {
    
            unregisterReceiver(WifiStateChangeReceiver())
    
    
            super.onDestroy()
    
        }
    
    }
```

The error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: bd.maruf.ruwifimanager, PID: 5669
                                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop service bd.maruf.ruwifimanager.ExampleService@259d834: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: bd.maruf.ruwifimanager.WifiStateChangeReceiver@8f5af07
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopService(ActivityThread.java:4375)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:237)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1956)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: bd.maruf.ruwifimanager.WifiStateChangeReceiver@8f5af07
                                                                                                        at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1435)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1642)
                                                                                                        at android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:715)
                                                                                                        at bd.maruf.ruwifimanager.ExampleService.onDestroy(Test.kt:25)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopService(ActivityThread.java:4355)
```